# having difficulties with facebook php api?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

okay so on my page in the meta data when viewing the source code it says

```
<html>
<head>
<title>YourGag - Gag</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="MyGag - Gag" />
<meta property="og:type" content="activity" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://blaze-craft.com/matt/gag.php?id=2" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://blaze-craft.com/matt/get.php?id=2" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="YourGag" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1254694731" />

</head>
```

but when i use the facebook debugger it says this

```
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:title" content="MyGag - Gag" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:type" content="activity" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:url" content="http://blaze-craft.com/matt/gag.php?id=0"     />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:image" content="http://blaze-craft.com/matt/get.php?  id=0" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:site_name" content="YourGag" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="fb:admins" content="1254694731" />
```

as you can see the id is different any ideas why this is happening?

thanks

:)

Comment: `
<meta property="og:image" content="http://blaze-craft.com/matt/get.php?id=2" />
`
What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> **Body Meta**:    You have `<meta>` tags ouside of your `<head>`. This is either
>   because your `<head>` was malformed and they fell lower in the parse
>   tree, or you accidentally put your Open Graph tags in the wrong place.
>   Either way you need to fix it before the tags are usable.